# Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() deprecation and OBB file location

Tags: android

I was using now deprecated `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get expansion (OBB) files location, which I constructed like:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/obb/" + packageName + "/"
```

with result like:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/obb/com.app.ID/
```

How am I supposed to get such a location now?
If I use `getExternalFilesDir()`, I will end with location like:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.app.ID/files
```

Am I supposed to store OBB files there instead of the original OBB location, use some sort of relative path or what? Am I only one who must deal with expansion files and care that these must be downloaded if user deletes them?

This never ending Android API deprecation with need to target the latest API makes me crazy:/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `getContext().getObbDir()`
Read  [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getObbDir())

Comment: Thanks a lot.. that change makes sense... could work a few months.. as it looks that complete OBB concept will be deprecated next year with [Play Assets Delivery](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/asset-delivery), so I will need to rewrite our game's internals again.. that is never ending work.

Comment: Hm.. am I right that to support API18, I should keep also the old version, when `getObbDir` is from API19? That would be probably the reason why I was using the old method until now:-/

Comment: Unfortunatelly I have one more issue with `getObbDir`... for some reason it returns location on external storage, but when I install the app from Google Play, the file is located in the _internal_ storage. This is really such a mess.